# AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation (Speech-recognition)

Tags: python, pip, conda, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I am using Spyder-IDE and i am trying to make a speach to text classifier with `speech_recognition` but the problem is every time i run my code i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\Stuff\untitled0.py", line 6, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")

AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

yay aren't thoose the words of joy? `AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation`
is there a way to fix this error?

i also have tried these methods to download PyAudio

`pip install PyAudio`

`conda install PyAudio`

but nothing seems to work.

this is my speech to text code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer


with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = sr.listen(source)
    
    print(audio)
```

Comment: hi, interesting, you might need to install the portaudio dependency libportaudio-dev or portaudio19-dev

Comment: 9 times out of 10 this is because you have two Python versions installed, and you're installing modules into one of them but running your code with another.  This is really easy to do if you're installing modules at the command line but running your code from an IDE.

Comment: Unless you got errors when trying to install PyAudio, it shouldn't be a matter of those other dependencies not being installed.  You'd get a different error...probably something specific to one of those dependencies.

Comment: @Steve i am using Spyder as my IDE

Comment: Which IDE you're using isn't probably isn't the issue.  The IDE thing is that an IDE usually lets you set which Python version you want to use independent of what is being used at the command line.  If you have them set to different versions of Python and you then install new modules at the command line, the code you're running in the IDE won't benefit by those installs.

Answer (score 1):

[pyaudio extentions](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

Find pyaudio section and download the file.

Here is a video tutorial to help you solving the error,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IiqgHpMEaAM